# ReactPY File upload and content checking

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, web

I'm using Reactpy for my project

and in it i find myself in need to upload a file.
return html.input(
{"type":"file",'on_change':handleFile}
)
here, before sending it to the server i want to check its content. Is there anyway in reactPY to check the uploaded file's content.